# How to perform SCAN operation for a key group in Pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Experts, i am trying to perform a scan kind of operation in a pyspark dataframe where i am marking end dates on records based on the next record in key groups. This is what my dataframe looks like-

```
+---+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|Key|col1|col2|     effective_date|           end_date|
+---+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|  X| ABC| DEF|2020-08-01 00:00:00|2999-12-31 00:00:00|
|  X|ABC1|DEF1|2020-08-03 00:00:00|2999-12-31 00:00:00|
|  X|ABC2|DEF2|2020-08-05 00:00:00|2999-12-31 00:00:00|
|  Y| PQR| STU|2020-08-07 00:00:00|2999-12-31 00:00:00|
|  Y|PQR1|STU1|2020-08-09 00:00:00|2999-12-31 00:00:00|
+---+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Desired Outout-

```
+---+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|Key|col1|col2|     effective_date|           end_date|
+---+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|  X| ABC| DEF|2020-08-01 00:00:00|2020-08-02 23:59:59|
|  X|ABC1|DEF1|2020-08-03 00:00:00|2020-08-04 23:59:59|
|  X|ABC2|DEF2|2020-08-05 00:00:00|2999-12-31 00:00:00|
|  Y| PQR| STU|2020-08-07 00:00:00|2020-08-08 23:59:59|
|  Y|PQR1|STU1|2020-08-09 00:00:00|2999-12-31 00:00:00|
+---+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

The field to group records here is "Key" and i would like to keep only one record with end_date "2999-12-31 00:00:00' in the key group. All other records i would like to mark expired and the end date is decided based on next record's effective date -1 when we put the records in order of their effective dates.
i tried below-

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> from pyspark.sql import Window
>>> w = Window.partitionBy("Key").orderBy("effective_date")
>>> df1=df.withColumn("end_date",F.date_sub(F.lead("effective_date").over(w), 1))
```

The Output doesn't look right with this. I am using Python 2.7 and Spark 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with **`lead`** like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w=Window().partitionBy("Key").orderBy("effective_date")

df.withColumn("lead", F.lead("effective_date").over(w))\
  .withColumn("end_date", F.when(F.col("lead").isNotNull(), F.expr("""lead - interval 1 second"""))\
                           .otherwise(F.col("end_date"))).drop("lead")\
  .orderBy("effective_date").show()

#+---+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
#|Key|col1|col2|     effective_date|           end_date|
#+---+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
#|  X| ABC| DEF|2020-08-01 00:00:00|2020-08-02 23:59:59|
#|  X|ABC1|DEF1|2020-08-03 00:00:00|2020-08-04 23:59:59|
#|  X|ABC2|DEF2|2020-08-05 00:00:00|2999-12-31 00:00:00|
#|  Y| PQR| STU|2020-08-07 00:00:00|2020-08-08 23:59:59|
#|  Y|PQR1|STU1|2020-08-09 00:00:00|2999-12-31 00:00:00|
#+---+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks